# Finding highest value in array however with assigned numbers to characters

Tags: c#, arrays

i have a quick question

```
A = 10
B = 11
C = 12
D = 13
```

I have an char array 
"5623ADCB"

I would want to find the biggest value which is D = 13 but the program doesn't recognize D = 13 when i use a for loop to look for the biggest number. Instead it outputs the D's ascii value, how do i make ensure that everytime a D is encountered, it would be recognized as 13 and not it's ascii value?

Thanks guys for your help

Comment: Hi guys, yes. D = 13, typo. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @JackYeoh Why don't you share what you've got so far?

Comment: Hi, sorry if my question was a little unclear. Basically, i want to assign a DEC value of 13 to D so that when i loop through it, it will output the character that is specific to my requirements. It's required as part of my assignment is to loop through your standard card deck, however once it passes 9, characters are introduced instead to keep it down to 1 char. T = 10, J = 11, Q=12, K=13.

Comment: Also, the size of the char array is unknown as the amount of "cards" i may receive is depended on the number of players, thus mapping DEC value to those chars are the best so that everytime T is encountered, it will automatically assume T = 10, J = 11..etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

functional recipe: make a map from Char to Int - use `Max`:

```
static int Map(char c)
{
    return Int32.Parse (c.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}

var max = "5623ADCB".Select (Map).Max ();
```

get's you `13` in this case ;)

---

here is a version if you are concerned with memory and performance:

```
static int FindMax(string s)
{
    s = s.ToUpper ();
    var max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        var v = Map (s [i]);
        if (v > max)
            max = v;
    }
    return max;
}

static int Map(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return (int)c - (int)'0';
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'E')
        return (int)c - (int)'A' + 10;

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ();
}
```

btw: I have no clue why you want `14` if you want `D` to be 13 - if the first was a typo then you have to change the `Map` function above (a `switch` will do if you don't want to get fancy) - as your first definition was exactly the same you would assume from Hex I went with it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov nope ... just `(int)c` will get you `68` in this case (which should be the encoding - the *trick* is the `NumberStyles.HexNumber` part you cannot get with direct casts AFAIK

Comment: and if you are really concerned about preformance and memory footprint just use a switch for all 16 cases and use a loop - it's no big deal really it just makes the code more ugly ...

Comment: Oh, that OP wants hexadecimal value. I missed that (or rather, he should of explicitly state it).

Comment: he said "want to find the biggest value which is D=14" - while I find the 14 strange as well I think he stated it - ofc I might be wrong to - so let's the op decide ...

Comment: Nice @Carsten ! Btw, `c - '0'` etc. will result in an `int` so no need for all those casts.

Comment: @async yes thank you - I tend to be over-careful when I don't want to check the code against the compiler ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get the greater value?

```
var array = "5623ADCB".ToCharArray();
Console.WriteLine(array.Max());
```

Or, to make sure "D" gets translated to "13", transform it from hexadecimal:

```
var array = "5623ADCB".ToCharArray();
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(array.Max().ToString(), 16));
```

Notice the `Convert.ToInt32(string, int)` method, which receives the numeric base to translate the string expression.